# Converting several binary columns to multilabel array

Tags: keras, multilabel-classification

I have several binary outcome variables (see below), that I'd like to encode into a single column y that can be used for a multilabel keras model in python.

```
has_carinsurance   has_lifeinsurance   has_petinsurance

1                   0                   1
```

So far, I've created the column y using

`df['y'] = df[['has_carinsurance','has_lifeinsurance','has_petinsurance']].values.tolist()`

How would I convert this to an array suitable for multilabel classification in python while making the original labels retrievable?

Comment: What would be the expected output for 101?